# Cannot implicitly convert type SqlBoolean to bool, or can you?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, implicit-conversion

Consider the following lines of code:

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean sb = true; // (1)

bool b = sb; // (2)

bool b = sb ? true : false; // (3)

if (sb) // (4)
{

}
```

**(1)** works fine, I guess because of `public static implicit operator SqlBoolean(bool x)`.

**(2)** gives me the following error ([CS0266](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z8wb9e4.aspx)):

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I understand that the conversion from `bool` to `SqlBoolean` is explicit (`public static explicit operator bool(SqlBoolean x)`), possibly because `SqlBoolean.IsNull` may be true.

But then why do **(3)** and **(4)** work? These look like implicit conversions.

Comment: Have you tried `bool b = (bool)sb;`?

Comment: I don't get your point, as this is as explicit as it can get.

Comment: I wanted to say that, there's only one way to achieve: using explicit conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I understand that the conversion from bool to SqlBoolean is explicit (public static explicit operator bool(SqlBoolean x)), possibly because SqlBoolean.IsNull may be true.

That is correct, so to cast `SqlBoolean` to `bool`, you must do so explicitly.
However, `SqlBoolean` also defines the `true` and `false` operators. ([true operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlboolean.op_true(v=vs.110).aspx))
Both the `if` statement and the ternary operator call the `true` operator to get a boolean value. They do not call the conversion operator.

You can have any type work with if-statements:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        if (p) {
            //prints 'calling true operator'
        }
    }

    public static bool operator true(Program p) {
        Console.WriteLine("calling true operator");
        return true;
    }

    public static bool operator false(Program p) {
        Console.WriteLine("calling false operator");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't know about these operators, interesting! Now trying to figure out what the `false` operator is good for. Seems like it's used for evaluating the `&&` operator.

Comment: Yup, it's used by `And`

Answer (score 0):

Case #1, #3, #4 works because SqlBoolean implements the true and false operator so it can interact with/behave as a bool.

Case #2 doesn't work because there is no SqlBoolean operator for bool to implement and hence bool doesn't know what to do when you tell it to interact with SqlBoolean.

For more information about the true false operator see
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d.aspx